# ONLYOFFICE and mime-types assosiasions

Tags: mime-types, onlyoffice, elementary-os

I`m using Elementary Os Loki and wanted to use ONLYOFFICE.
I tried installing the last deb file from official site and tried to use the repo(no change). The problem is that when the package installs it doesn`t register itself to allow opening the file from filemanager or terminal(desktopeditors -f example.doc or smth).
I found whole dir in the official repo where I think all logic is handled.

(https://github.com/ONLYOFFICE/desktop-apps/tree/master/win-linux/package/linux/qt-installer/packages/onlyoffice/data)

I also tried to fix  by changing file in /usr/share/applications - defaults.list and desktopeditors.desktop.

Please fix this or give a nice explaination if it a feature.
The only way to open a file is to use internal file chooser dialog or to drag&drop a file on the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug in onlyoffice-desktopeditors. We will fix it soon. You can set file associations:  open context menu of the file, choose "open with" -> "other applications". Then find 'desktopeditors' in recommended applications, select this and press 'Set as default' button.
After this you will be able to open files from file manager in ONLYOFFICE.

Comment: I have tried this and it doesn`t work. It`s a desktopeditors file bug I think. It not a binary executable and its a shel file which must preconfigure smth/

Comment: Yes, it bug. In the new version .desktop file will contain correct Mime types with all of supported formats

Comment: Can you respond here when the new version will be available?

Comment: @andrew-k We hope we can release it in two weeks